# Datatable Invalid JSON response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatable

I have a problem with Datatables. 
Until now, everything worked like a charm, now, from reasons unknown to me, datatables stopped working on my app.

My datatable ajax call is returning:

`DataTables warning: table id=section-list - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1`

My datatables init:

```
 sections.find('table#section-list').dataTable({
        "ajax": '/admin/page/get-section-list',
        "columns": [
            {"data": "SectionID"},
            {"data": "SectionAlias"},
            {"data": "Edit"},
            {"data": "Delete"},
        ], aoColumnDefs: [
            {
                bSortable: false,
                aTargets: [-1, -2, -3] // disable sorting on last three columns (icons)
            }
        ]
    });
```

and my page/get-section-list action

```
....
return new JsonModel(["data" => $sections]); // this is equivalent to echo json_encode() in basic php
```

I tested my JSON in Json Parser AND it is 100% ok and there is no previous output before this json.

Im using DataTables 1.10.3 with jQuery v1.10.2

Comment: inspect actual request in browser console network tab to see what's actually sent. Is it what is expected and does the format match the datatables expected input?

Comment: if nothing set in my database this is output: "{"data":[]}" so yes... everythig as expected

Comment: Just a guess - would it work if you remove the `,` after `{"data": "Delete"},` ?

Comment: nope, result is the same

Comment: What is sent in the request as json? Please provide example json that does not work and triggers the error.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem working with a data.json file and found the information from [here](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/1) very helpful. Specifically the recommendation to open chrome dev tools, click the network tab, and then try the request again so you can see it in the network timeline.

In my case it looked like the json file in my `"ajax": '/path/to/data.json'` was still being written to at the same time the reload request was trying to access the data. Adding a delay around the reload request to give data.json time to complete solved the issue:

```
setTimeout(
function() {
  $('#tableid').DataTable().ajax.reload(null, false);
}, 125);
```

But its hard to know what the optimal delay setting should be. So instead of doing the `settimeout()` (which works btw), I changed how I was writing my data from nodejs asynchronous `fs.writeFile()` to the synchronous `fs.writeFileSync()` when writing to the file.

Every case will be a little different but if you know the data source normally returns valid json, you may want to inspect if that source is changing at the same time datatables is trying to access it.